# Contention issues due to indexing "_expires" property - Sessions on Google App Engine [Java]

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I've noticed that the `_expires` property of `_ah_SESSION` is indexed. This surely comes handy when querying for expired sessions. But there seems to be a downside to this. The `_expires` property contains monotonically increasing values. Which means that index records for this property will most likely end up on a single tablet server. I am concerned that such tablet server could be easily overloaded by applications which update session data often. Is there a way of telling App Engine NOT to index the `_expires` property? Perhaps something along the lines of adding a rule to `appengine-web.xml`, for example:

```
<session-index-expiration>false</session-index-expiration>
```

To the best of my knowledge, answer to my question is "no". I am thinking of submitting a feature request. But maybe I am missing something. Your input will be much appreciated.

**Update 1:** I filed a feature request for this. Please consider giving it a vote by "starring" it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71583968

**Update 2:** The feature request was noticed by Google and "a solution is currently being investigated". In the issue tracker discussion, there is a post saying that it *may* be possible to prevent the `_expires` property from being indexed by means of `datastore-indexes.xml` configuration file. However, since this file seems to deal exclusively with declaring custom indexes, I fail to see how it can be used to disable a single property index. Any ideas?

PS: I originally believed the somewhat widespread myth that `_ah_SESSION` entities are automatically rewritten after every request merely to update the expiration timestamp. But this is not true. According to the actual [implementation of SessionManager](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-vm-runtime/blob/master/appengine-jetty-managed-runtime/src/main/java/com/google/apphosting/runtime/jetty9/SessionManager.java), such rewrites are enforced only when the session is at least 25% expired. Which significantly reduces the risk of contention caused by indexing the `_expires` property. At least for applications which use sessions mainly to keep track of logged in/out users.